# Можно ли в Битрикс в поле вебформы типа dropdown выводить элементы другого инфоблока?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно выпадающий список в веб-форме заполнить городами, список которых уже имеется в соответствующем инфоблоке.

А также другой выпад. список заполнять подразделениями, соответствующими выбранному городу.

Это возможно средствами Битрикса? Если да, то как? В настройках полей веб-формы такого не нашел.

Comment: Можно если настроите связку инфоблоков городов и подразделений. Но скорее всего придется немного подправить шаблон формы кодом, чтобы вмешаться выбор.

Answer (score 1):

1. Копируете шаблон формы себе
2. Добавляете в него result_modifier, в котором получаете список ваших городов (смотрите CIblockElement::GetList в документации)
3. Добавляете в шаблон вывод городов в ваш список